# Extract all Active Directory users

Tags: node.js, active-directory

I used this piece of code to extract all AD users:

```
var ActiveDirectory = require('activedirectory');

var ad = new ActiveDirectory({ url: 'ldap://domain.com',
                               baseDN: 'dc=domain,dc=com',
                               username: 'user@domain.com',
                               password: 'password',
                               attributes: {
                                 user: [ 'givenName', 'mail', 'mobile' ],
                                //  group: [ 'anotherCustomAttribute', 'objectCategory' ]
                               }
                              });

ad.findUsers(function(err, users) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('ERROR: ' +JSON.stringify(err));
        return;
    }
 
    if ((! users) || (users.length == 0)) 
        console.log('No users found.');
    else {
        console.log('findUsers: '+JSON.stringify(users));
    }
});
```

Also it extracted most of the users, but it doesn't extract all of them. For example, if I have 500 users, it extracts 412 users.

What's wrong and how can I extract all of the users?

Comment: Is there something in common between the 88 it didn't return?

Comment: @GabrielLuci Yes, all of them are created after a specific period of time (For example after March 13, 2021 - 8:29)

Comment: Do you have more than one domain controller? I wonder if you're having problems with replication.

Comment: @GabrielLuci I'm not sure about the number of domain controllers, but when I extract users using powershell it extracts all users, but when I try using node js, It extracts users that are created before a specific point of time.